# Using a volume with a redmine docker container in Bluemix

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, redmine, volumes

I am trying to set up a Redmine instance in a Bluemix container, using the Redmine official Docker;

I can build the image and run the container with no problems.

If I add a volume to the container the build fail near the end with this log:

> chown: cannot read directory 'files/files': Permission denied
>
> 8chown: changing ownership of 'files': Permission denied

I understand this is happening because the user in the container has no read/write privileges.

I have tried some solution attempts such as using

> USER root

Before the chown.
Even declaring the volume only after the chown (as suggested in the Docker page)

Alternatively, all the other solutions I've come across involve ssh to the container; what I cannot do as the container never runs ins the first place with the volume.

here is a copy of my Dockerfile and entrypoint.sh

```
FROM ruby:2.2-slim


# add the volumeeditor to grant permissions in bluemix
RUN groupadd --gid 1010 redmine
RUN useradd --uid 1010 --gid 1010 -m --shell /bin/bash redmine


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.7
RUN set -x \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && gosu nobody true

# grab tini for signal processing and zombie killing
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.9.0
RUN set -x \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/tini "https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/$TINI_VERSION/tini" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/tini.asc "https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/$TINI_VERSION/tini.asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 6380DC428747F6C393FEACA59A84159D7001A4E5 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/tini.asc /usr/local/bin/tini \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/tini.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tini \
    && tini -h

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        imagemagick \
        libmysqlclient18 \
        libpq5 \
        libsqlite3-0 \
        \
        bzr \
        git \
        mercurial \
        openssh-client \
        subversion \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV RAILS_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/redmine

ENV REDMINE_VERSION 3.3.3
ENV REDMINE_DOWNLOAD_MD5 c946839c9a51dba48ae7c34c5351f677

RUN wget -O redmine.tar.gz "https://www.redmine.org/releases/redmine-${REDMINE_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && echo "$REDMINE_DOWNLOAD_MD5 redmine.tar.gz" | md5sum -c - \
    && tar -xvf redmine.tar.gz --strip-components=1 \
    && rm redmine.tar.gz files/delete.me log/delete.me \
    && mkdir -p tmp/pdf public/plugin_assets \
    && chown -R redmine:redmine ./

RUN buildDeps=' \
        gcc \
        libmagickcore-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        make \
        patch \
    ' \
    && set -ex \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && bundle install --without development test \
    && for adapter in mysql2 postgresql sqlite3; do \
        echo "$RAILS_ENV:" > ./config/database.yml; \
        echo "  adapter: $adapter" >> ./config/database.yml; \
        bundle install --without development test; \
    done \
    && rm ./config/database.yml \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

VOLUME /usr/src/redmine/files

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
    local var="$1"
    local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
    local def="${2:-}"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ] && [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        echo >&2 "error: both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
        exit 1
    fi
    local val="$def"
    if [ "${!var:-}" ]; then
        val="${!var}"
    elif [ "${!fileVar:-}" ]; then
        val="$(< "${!fileVar}")"
    fi
    export "$var"="$val"
    unset "$fileVar"
}

case "$1" in
    rails|rake|passenger)
        if [ ! -f './config/database.yml' ]; then
            file_env 'REDMINE_DB_MYSQL'
            file_env 'REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES'
            
            if [ "$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP" ] && [ -z "$REDMINE_DB_MYSQL" ]; then
                export REDMINE_DB_MYSQL='mysql'
            elif [ "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP" ] && [ -z "$REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES" ]; then
                export REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES='postgres'
            fi
            
            if [ "$REDMINE_DB_MYSQL" ]; then
                adapter='mysql2'
                host="$REDMINE_DB_MYSQL"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_PORT' '3306'
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_USERNAME' "${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER:-root}"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD' "${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_PASSWORD:-${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-}}"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_DATABASE' "${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE:-${MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER:-redmine}}"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_ENCODING' ''
            elif [ "$REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES" ]; then
                adapter='postgresql'
                host="$REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_PORT' '5432'
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_USERNAME' "${POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD' "${POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_DATABASE' "${POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_DB:-${REDMINE_DB_USERNAME:-}}"
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_ENCODING' 'utf8'
            else
                echo >&2
                echo >&2 'warning: missing REDMINE_DB_MYSQL or REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES environment variables'
                echo >&2
                echo >&2 '*** Using sqlite3 as fallback. ***'
                echo >&2
                
                adapter='sqlite3'
                host='localhost'
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_PORT' ''
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_USERNAME' 'redmine'
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD' ''
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_DATABASE' 'sqlite/redmine.db'
                file_env 'REDMINE_DB_ENCODING' 'utf8'
                
                mkdir -p "$(dirname "$REDMINE_DB_DATABASE")"
                chown -R redmine:redmine "$(dirname "$REDMINE_DB_DATABASE")"
            fi
            
            REDMINE_DB_ADAPTER="$adapter"
            REDMINE_DB_HOST="$host"
            echo "$RAILS_ENV:" > config/database.yml
            for var in \
                adapter \
                host \
                port \
                username \
                password \
                database \
                encoding \
            ; do
                env="REDMINE_DB_${var^^}"
                val="${!env}"
                [ -n "$val" ] || continue
                echo "  $var: \"$val\"" >> config/database.yml
            done
        fi
        
        # ensure the right database adapter is active in the Gemfile.lock
        bundle install --without development test
        
        if [ ! -s config/secrets.yml ]; then
            file_env 'REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE'
            if [ "$REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE" ]; then
                cat > 'config/secrets.yml' <<-YML
                    $RAILS_ENV:
                      secret_key_base: "$REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE"
                YML
            elif [ ! -f /usr/src/redmine/config/initializers/secret_token.rb ]; then
                rake generate_secret_token
            fi
        fi
        if [ "$1" != 'rake' -a -z "$REDMINE_NO_DB_MIGRATE" ]; then
            gosu redmine rake db:migrate
        fi
        
        # https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-8-File-system-permissions
        mkdir -p tmp tmp/pdf public/plugin_assets
        chown -R redmine:redmine files log public/plugin_assets
        chmod -R 755 files log tmp public/plugin_assets
        
        # remove PID file to enable restarting the container
        rm -f /usr/src/redmine/tmp/pids/server.pid
        
        if [ "$1" = 'passenger' ]; then
            # Don't fear the reaper.
            set -- tini -- "$@"
        fi
        
        set -- gosu redmine "$@"
        ;;
esac

exec "$@"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this, you have to temporarily add the non-root user to the root group to grant it write permissions on the volume mount. Here's an example in the documentation: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_volumes_ov.html#container_volumes_write

Comment: I played around with it with the info in the documentation and finally got it working. Thanks!